# Performance hit of static_cast pointer types?

Tags: c++

How much would `static_cast` 10,000 items of pointer types take?

Comment: nothing, it's done at compile time, for pointers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Nitpicker's corner

Other answers pointed out that the cost is zero for pointers; this is correct as far as class hierarchies with single inheritance are involved, but when dealing with multiple inheritance there may be a (very small) cost.

In single-inheritance classes the memory layout of objects is typically arranged so that a pointer to a derived class can be used as a pointer to base class with no adjustments - this is normally accomplished by putting the "parent part" of the object at the front, so that a pointer to Derived is actually also a valid pointer to Base.

But in multiple-inheritance scenarios, you cannot put *all* the base classes in front of the object; for this reason, when casting a `Derived *` to `Base1 *` or to `Base2 *`, a pointer adjustment may be needed. This typically results in a fixed-size increment to the pointer when doing various operations that involve a pointer to one of the base classes.

Of course, this is *completely* negligible (it amounts to a single really fast assembly instruction at most), but nonetheless, in this scenario there *is* a *very very slight* cost in cast. Notice though that it's not specific to `static_cast`, it's there whenever you need to treat your `Derived *` as a `Base2 *` (including when you simply call `Base2 *` methods, since also the `this` pointer needs to be adjusted).

Additional reading: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12935/What-static_cast-is-actually-doing

Comment: This is a great answer, but I'm really struggling to see the pun.

Comment: @paddy: http://www.xkcd.com/559/ (no, actually I was just amused by "cost in cast", but it's not properly a pun :) )

Comment: Hehehe, that comic puts it all into perspective.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing, it's done at compile time, for pointers. But it's not zero cost for an actual object where work has to be done to convert between types. When you static_cast a pointer all that's really being done is you look at the address in a different way. The casting of an actual object can involve the creation of a temporary and thus has runtime cost of the conversion operator used to create it.

Answer (score 2):

casting should take 0 time, no matter how many times*

*there is a noted exception of pointers in multiple-inheritance scenarios where pointer manipulation must occur, but for cases of single inheritance that static_cast is mearly allowing the code to derefference the pointer in a different way:

take for example:

```
foo(void *x)
{
    int * j=static_cast<int *>(x);  // costs the same as void *x2=x;
    // the cast above does nothing except allow the copy of the pointer value to j and allow the line below to work
    int k = *j;    // this would not be allowed directly from x without the static_cast
}
```

had `x` been multiply inherited instead and cast to a base then the cast would move the pointer to the correct start of base.  And not been 0 cost.

Comment: Casting does, indeed, take 0 time. But the **conversion** that the cast tells the compiler to do might not.

Comment: Aside from the conversions that have a cost, conversions have no cost.

Comment: Part of my point was the difference between **cast** and **convert**. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion.

Comment: @PeteBecker - according to the standards, it seems that `int x=0; x=static_cast<int>(x);` is a conversion, but in general usage a cast allows viewing the data differently, a conversion implies a change, so one would say cast it through `void *`, and not convert it through `void *`

Comment: Indeed, one could say whatever one wished to say if one were not concerned with precise communication. If you use **cast** to refer to something that is **not** a cast, then when you want to refer to something that **is** a cast what will you call it?